# Got NullException when dealing with UploadedFile Tapestry5

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm working with Tapestry, and this is fairly new to me. In my application, I use UploadedFile to get user chosen file, but when I want to get its filename, I've got NullException. What is wrong?

Declaration for documentFile :

```
@org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property
private UploadedFile documentFile;
```

Method that will executed when to saving :

```
@XHR
Object onSelectedFromSaveDocument() {
    String fileName = UploadFileUtils.saveFile(documentFile, DocRoot);
    this.curDocument.setType(curFileType.getValue());
    this.curDocument.setPath(fileName);
    if(this.getDocumentByKeys(this.curDocument.getDescription()) != null) {
        this.propertyDocumentDAO.merge(this.curDocument);
    } else {
        curDocument.setPropertyCode(selectedCode);
        this.propertyDocumentDAO.create(this.curDocument);
    }
    return onActionFromCancelDocument();
}
```

UploadFileUtils.java :

```
public class UploadFileUtils {
    public static String saveFile(UploadedFile file, String fileDir) {
        if(!fileDir.endsWith(File.separator)) {
            fileDir = fileDir+File.separator;
        }
        File dir = new File(fileDir);
        if(!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        String fileExt = file.getFileName();

        int dotPos = fileExt.lastIndexOf(".");
        if(dotPos >= 0) {
            fileExt = fileExt.substring(dotPos+1);
        }
        File copied = new File(fileDir+DateUtils.getDateTimeString()+"."+fileExt);
        file.write(copied);
        return copied.getName();
    }
}
```

The line that throws Null Exception is:

```
String fileName = UploadFileUtils.saveFile(documentFile, DocRoot);
```

and this...

```
String fileExt = file.getFileName();
```

UPDATE:

This is my ViewProperty.tml

```
<t:if test="creatingDocument">
    <input t:type="upload" t:id="file" t:value="documentFile"
        validate="required" />
```

And this is my DocRoot

```
private final String DocRoot = this.configManager.getString("DocRoot", "/FileUpload/DocRoot/");
```

configManager

```
@InjectService("BosConfigManager")
private BosConfigManager configManager;
```

Comment: paste the code directly please.. avoid screenshots of code

Comment: @suraj I'm using Linux through RDC to code, and cannot copy paste. My company not allowed and not provide me internet in my env

Comment: try to add `@org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Persist` Annotation to documentFile, It may solve the problem

Comment: Other question, what is `DocRoot` where is it from? pls add more detail, and I suggest you to check the parameters in your method that they are `null` or not.

Comment: @LakiGeri hi, I've added the persist, but still not work :(

Comment: @HobasMatius It is a pity that your company doesn't allow you copy the code, but it should NOT be a problem of us and all other future readers of your question. Change an employer or write code as a text.

Comment: @Andremoniy I know, but for the mean time, can you please help me. I've changed the formatting to help you read better

Comment: Now. Spend your time to translate image into the text.

Comment: @Andremoniy Done, now can you help me?

Comment: why don't you check the paramateres at the begining of method?
`if(file == null || fileDir == null) { log.error("file or fileDir is null!"); return null;}` I almost sure that your `file` parameter is `null` so the problem is not comes from your `saveFile` method.

Comment: @LakiGeri ya, now I'm guessing the same, because when I call `documentFile.getName();` at `onSelectedFromSaveDocument`, it throwing null. But I have no idea, it should work.

Comment: I'm not a tapestry expert as well, My first suggestion that you should initialise the `documentFile` variable in `onPrepareForRender`

Comment: @LakiGeri sorry, how to do that anyway?

Comment: Like this: `void onPrepareForRender() { documentFile = new UploadedFile();}`.

Comment: @LakiGeri the type `UploadedFile` cannot be instantiated